# Using JSF/Mojarra on IE7/IE8: Request is not applied

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have a quite complicated table website in which I want to browse with pages (e.g. 5 rows at a time). This browsing works great in Firefox, but does not in Internet Explorer (7 + 8).

I investigated the HTTP traffic and found out, that the response generated by the server is correct, but in IE the content is just not updated (also no error messages, e.g. in the console). I spent the whole day creating a sandbox example, but unfortunately all smaller examples work perfectly. I am now considering two things:

- My response is too big for IE7/IE8 JS engine to handle.
- The response contains some sequences not digestable by IE7/IE8 JS engine or Mojarra.

Are you aware of any such bugs in Mojarra / IE JS? I am using Mojarra 2.1.3.

The browsing is triggered by an ajax command link:

```
<h:commandLink value="&gt;" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.tblModel.nextPage}">
  <f:ajax execute=":#{cc.attrs.tblId}" render=":#{cc.attrs.tblId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

As I think the problem could be the exact response, here is an original response (stripped down the minimum that still doesn't work):

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
    <update id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent"><![CDATA[<div id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent">
    <span class="table-total">Total Elemente 
        <strong>58</strong>
    </span> 
    <span class="table-pro-seite">Anzahl Elemente pro Seite Anzeigen: 
          
        <span class="selected">5</span> 
         |  
        <a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:j_idt555:j_idt244" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false">10</a> 
         |  
        <a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:j_idt555:j_idt250" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false">20</a> 

    </span>
    <div class="table-content">


    </div><div id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:table-footer" class="table-footer">
<div id="tableFooter">
    <div class="table-paging"><a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:firstLink" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false" class="table-paging-firstLink">&lt;&lt;</a><a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:previousLink" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false" class="table-paging-previousLink">&lt;</a>

            <span class="table-paging-currentpage">Seite<input id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:currentPage" type="text" name="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:currentPage" value="2" class="table-input" onkeypress="return displayedPageKeypressEvent(event);" />von 12<input id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:sendDisplayedPage" type="submit" name="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:sendDisplayedPage" value="send" style="visibility: hidden; float: right;" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false" />
            </span><span id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:pageSelector"><a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:nextLink" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false" class="table-paging-nextLink">&gt;</a><a id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:lastLink" href="#" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent','tableForm:resultsPanel:tableComponent');return false" class="table-paging-lastLink">&gt;&gt;</a></span></div><span id="tableForm:resultsPanel:tableFooter:table-footer-multiselect"></span>
    </div></div></div>]]></update>
    <extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

Thank you very much for any help!

PS: I am also using Primefaces, but I guess this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: What Mojarra version exactly? Have you tried the latest? (currently 2.1.3)

Comment: Sorry, I am using the latest version: Mojarra 2.1.3

Comment: Are there any errors in IE's JS console?

Comment: no, there aren't. No errors whatsoever, only the request is not applied

Comment: Try IE8 JS debugger to step through `jsf.js` code line by line: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/03/13/jscript-debugger-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx True, cumbersome work, but as far now I can't be of more assistance as you're the only one who has all the code. No similar issues comes to mind and I also can't find anything similar in Mojarra bug tracker. By the way, does it work in IE9?

Comment: I started debugging and found out that IE says there are parse errors in the XML. It is complaining that the &#160; is an invalid character ... have you ever heard of such a problem? When I remove all &#160; and &nbsp; the request is correctly updated

Comment: That's very odd. `&nbsp;` is indeed invalid in XML (and should be the real cause of this problem), but `&#160;` is definitely not invalid in XML. Are you very sure that it also jerks on `&#160;`?

Comment: yes, both are wrong, (we use &#160; everywhere, just replaced that with nbsp as a desperate approach). So are all my other special chars, like ä and ö. Seems like some encoding error bundled with another minor error in jsf.ajax.getParseError that prevents any error messages from being displayed - which is rather unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will try creating a testcase later this day so that I can see/reproduce it myself and eventually find the fix.

Comment: Hey, we found out that there seem to be two default values, that JSF takes if there is no encoding given in the request:
one for the encoding in the header and one for the encoding of the content. The default for the content is UTF-8 the default for the header is ISO-8859. We intercepted the request and found out that IE7/8 doesn't include an encoding in it's request (firefox does). So we guess that IE got confuses by the ambiguous encoding definition. What is strange is, that if that should be right all IE7/8 users should have a problem with JSF, which would have probably already detected ...

Comment: We are now a bit more sure that it was this error, as the problem is solved by a custom filter that adds a character encoding if the request is partial and there is none set:   `HttpServletRequest sr = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  if (JSFUtils.isAjaxRequest(sr)) {
   if (sr.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
    sr.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
   }
  }`